# Excel - How to arrange columns as per the chronological months

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-office

In an Excel worksheet, I have a few columns
I would like to rearrange as per the chronological month. 
As of now, I've been doing that manually, and it is getting quite tedious.

I've tried to illustrate my problem here:

[image]

The month and year has been written as a text format instead of a date format
(in the form mmm'yy – including the apostrophe). 
What I tried to do was create a custom format for the months, and tried to rearrange rows on that basis, but custom sorting appears to be greyed out. 
I am a beginner at Excel, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The trick to good sorting is that Excel needs to know that it's a date.

You can convert the text in cell C3 (for example) to a date with this formula in C4:

```
=DATE(2000+RIGHT(C3,2),XLOOKUP(LEFT(C3,3),{"Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"},SEQUENCE(1,12)),1)
```

[image]

It looks long and unwieldy, but it's somewhat simple when broken down.

We're using the `DATE` function. This takes three arguments (separated by commas):

1. Year
2. Month
3. Day

The year is `2000+RIGHT(C3,2)`. This is just adding the right-most two characters from your text to 2000 to get the year. If you have dates before 2000, you'll need to adjust this part.

The month is `XLOOKUP(LEFT(C3,3),{"Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"},SEQUENCE(1,12))`. This is saying "Look for the first three characters in cell C3 in this list of months. Return the value from the same position (i.e. if Apr, the 4th position in the list), from `SEQUENCE(1,12)`." This SEQUENCE is just a list of numbers from 1 to 12. So we're converting the three-character month back to a number to use it in the DATE function.

The day is just 1. This can be any number less than or equal to 28, since all months have at least that many days.

So, for C3, the year is 2000+21, the month is Apr - i.e. the 4th month, so 4, and the day is 1. So we have `DATE(2021,4,1)`.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this formula as well in cell C4

```
=DATE(2000+RIGHT(C3,2),MONTH(1&LEFT(C3,3)),1)
```

Answer (score 1):

People are missing the function that’s specifically for this job.

Pick a “helper row”. 
It could be Row 4 or 999 or wherever you want to put it.

In Column C in that row (e.g., in Cell C4), enter

```
=DATEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(C3, "'", " 20"))
```

The `SUBSTITUTE` replaces the apostrophe with a space and `20`. 
For example, this changes `Apr'21` to `Apr 2021`. 
The `DATEVALUE` function then changes that text value
into the corresponding date value.

Then — the “obvious” part that nobody else mentioned —
you can sort your data by the helper row.

If you prefer, you can use

```
=DATEVALUE(LEFT(C3,3) & " 20" & RIGHT(C3,2))
```

If you might have data that are not in the 21st century
(i.e., year is not 20*yy*),
you will need to add logic to determine the century number.